# Count of dates over a period of time

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Table1 with Employee Data as below

`| empid | department |  startdate |   enddate  |
|   1   |      D1    | 2014-02-05 | 2014-06-18 |
|   1   |      D3    | 2013-08-29 | 2014-02-05 |
|   2   |      D3    | 2014-05-07 | 2014-06-18 |
|   2   |      D4    | 2013-08-29 | 2014-05-06 |
|   2   |      D3    | 2014-06-19 | 2014-12-01 |`

I have another table Table2 with their absence data

`empid    department  absentceDate
1           D3         2013-09-24
1           D3         2013-09-30
1           D3         2013-10-25
1           D1         2014-02-06

1           D1         2014-02-08 
2           D3         2013-08-30
2           D3         2013-09-30
2           D3         2013-10-30
2           D3         2014-11-11
2           D4         2014-05-10`

I joined both the tables to find count of absence dates for an employee based on empid using teh following code:

```
SELECT   T1.empid as empid,
                    T1.department as department,
                    COUNT(absencedate) AS NumDaysAbsent ,
                    startdate, enddate,

           FROM     Table1 T1
                    JOIN Table2 T2 SE ON sa.empid = se.empid
           GROUP BY T1.empid ,
                    T1.department
                    startdate, enddate
```

My results are as below

`empid    department    NumDaysAbsent startdat enddate
1        D1               5           2014-02-05   2014-06-18
1        D3               5           2013-08-29   2014-02-05
2        D3               5           2014-05-07   2014-06-18
2        D3               5           2014-06-19   2014-12-01
2        D4               5           2013-08-29   2014-05-06`

Instead I want to group numberofAbsences by department and diaply them as

`empid    department    NumDaysAbsent  startdate      enddate
1        D1               2           2014-02-05   2014-06-18
1        D3               3           2013-08-29   2014-02-05
2        D3               3           2014-05-07   2014-06-18
2        D3               1           2014-06-19   2014-12-01
2        D4               1           2013-08-29   2014-05-06`

How do i proceed? i've been trying to figure out how to achieve that. How do i group them by the startdate and enddate and excatly dipaly the number of absences for their period in that department?
Any inputs? I am trying to do this in SQL Server

Comment: can you post appropriate expected results so that we can understand better? For example , for empid 1 , the total absence from D1 should be 2 days while you said you are expecting 3 days. Likewise for actual results that you are getting. Are you getting 5 days of absence for all records?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, Jitesh. My expected output for emp1 for D1 is 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need more conditions on the join, including the department and the date.  My best guess is this:

```
SELECT   T1.empid as empid, T1.department as department,
         COUNT(absencedate) AS NumDaysAbsent ,
         startdate, enddate,
FROM     Table1 T1 JOIN
         Table2 T2
         ON t1.empid = t2.empid AND t1.department = t2.department and
            t2.absencedate between t1.startdate and t1.enddate
GROUP BY T1.empid, T1.department, startdate, enddate;
```

Comment: Thanks, gordon! That was a valuable input. You taught me to use between in where condition!